# Init element without ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code

```
View

<tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
   <td>
<input type="number" ng-model="inputAantal"  />
<div class='small button' ng-click="amountDecrease( order.code ,inputAantal )">
</td>
</tr>

Controller


  $scope.orders = privates.orders;
```

Now I would like to initialise inputAantal with a value which is also stored in order. But how can I do this and still bind the second parameter of the amountDecrease function to the input value? I could initialize all input fields in my controller but then I would lose my binding with the parameter of method amountDecrease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="order.value"  />
        <div class='small button' 
        ng-click="amountDecrease(order.code, order.value)">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: but when I change the input value, will the second parameter in amountDecrease also change? Because it still points to the original data in order

Comment: Yup. The second parameter would also change :)

Comment: Cool, I thought it would keep a binding with the value in the order object instead of the input value. will test

Comment: Indeed the binding works. Yet with only ng-model, the input field isn't initialised (shouldn't it be because of the model property). Should I use value or placemarker property for this?

Comment: I dont get it. Could you prepare a fiddle and explain your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/74B7z/
the method amountDecrease works fine, only on pageload the input field stays blank even when I add a value field.

Comment: Found error: tried to initialise with string instead of number